# ROS can't import third party libraries

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to use tkinter in my ROS environment but I am having some trouble getting it set up. I added it to my `packages.xml` file like this

```
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<depend>python-tk</depend>
<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
```

but when I install the package with `rosdep install [my package]`, the node I have `import tkinter` in still will not run, and instead returns `ImportError: No module named tkinter`. I am relatively new to ROS and have not installed third party packages before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a 3rd party library/package, ros *may not know* how to install it. If you installed properly, rosdep should have a cache of rules to install various packages, manually created by the community. If everything is ok, when you run `rosdep install my_new_pkg`, it should say `All required rosdeps installed successfully`, or on failure report

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
my_new_pkg: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [tkinter]
```

This means there's no rule for how to install it, predefined.
(Should it use pip/pip3? Search apt? apt install ros-version-tkinter or apt install tkinter?)
This is not to say it can't be done, but it is not done without the rule being added. It will still check that it is installed, however, if you install it by another means. You can try updating your cache to the global with `rosdep update`, but that didn't help me for tkinter.

This is the [rosdep tutorial for system deps](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosdep). If you have a bunch of 3rd pary python packages, you could do the normal python env + requirements.txt file.
(Biased ex, use pyenv+virtualenv + direnv to automatically call pip install on your requirements.txt)
Else, you can have a hook in your CMakeLists.txt file to call pip install on your requirements.txt file before each compile, or some other means.

Edit: Remember that ROS Melodic & older use python2. In python2, [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), it's `import Tkinter`. The lowercase import is a specification of python3.

Comment: I did get the "All required rosdeps installed successfully" message after running "rosdep install [package]", but it seems as though my nodes still can't make use of the dependencies it installed. Is there something I have to change or add to allow them to actually use the third party packages?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation on how to import it? I have no clue what versions you're using, but [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) certainly addresses older (even newer?) versions. Most likely, looking at the [official docs for py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) shows it as `import Tkinter` (note the capital! And that it's py2!). ROS, before Ubuntu20/Noetic, use py2, so it would fail if you try to use the py3 documentation, imports, or py3 code in general. If you want to use py3 code, there's a bunch of those questions on SO (and google).

Comment: Oh, it was the capitalization thing. Strange. Thanks for the help!